# I am unable to start a thread whiles implementing runnable can't seem to reproduce an error

Tags: java, multithreading

for some reason i cant seem to invoke the start() method when i am implementing Runnable

```
public class ThreadTest implements Runnable {
  
    public void run() {
    }
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadTest test = new ThreadTest();     
        test.start();
    }
}
```

I am getting the red wiggle line under start() saying that I need to either implement start or type cast test to object

I am unable to reproduce this error in online compiler either

[image]

I am beyond baffled as to what is causing this error
[image]

Comment: try ```new Thread(new ThreadTest()).start()``` - ```start``` is not defined on ```Runnable```, it is defined on the ```Thread``` class

Comment: awwwww im an idiot. the class was ectending thread and i changed it

Comment: It's a lot to keep straight in your head - don't sweat it too much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
public class ThreadTest implements Runnable {

  public void run() {
  }
    
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Thread test = new Thread(new ThreadTest());     
      test.start();
  }
}
```

another way:

```
public class ThreadTest extends Thread{

  public void run() {
  }
    
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      ThreadTest test = new ThreadTest();     
      test.start();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shoudn't call like

```
TestThread test=new TestThread();
test.start();
```

Correct way :

```
Thread thread=new Thread(new TestThread());
thread.start();
```

Either you can extend Thread class or implement Runnable class and override the run method so when u call start method it will execute the code inside the run method.